# A Short exact sequence with multiple base spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $D$ is a divisor on it.

Then there is the exact sequence

$0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}([D]) \to \mathcal{O}([D])|_D \to 0$

where $\mathcal{O} \cong \mathcal{O}([D] \otimes[D]^
{-1})$  is the sheaf of germs of holomophis functions on $M$ which is also interpreted as the set of holomorphic sections of the line bundle $[D]$ vanishing on $D$. $\mathcal{O}([D]) $ denotes the sheaf  of germs of holomorphic sections of the line bundle $[D]$ on $M$ and $\mathcal{O}([D])|_D$ denotes its restriction to $D$.

Then there is a long exact sequence with multiple base spaces.

$0 \to H^0(M, \mathcal{O}) \to H^0(M, \mathcal{O}([D])) \to H^0(D,   \mathcal{O}([D])|_D) \to  H^1(M, \mathcal{O}) \to ...$

Such a sequence with different base spaces (i.e.  $M,D$) is the first experience for me.

Is there any reference?
Or I am wrong?
Or one can prove it?

I guess there is some proposition such that 
any short exact sequence

$0 \to (X,\mathcal{F}) \to  (Y,\mathcal{G})  \to (Z,\mathcal{H}) \to 0$,

there is a long exact sequence

$0 \to H^0(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^0(Y, \mathcal{G} ) \to H^0(Z,   \mathcal{H} ) \to  H^1(X, \mathcal{F}) \to ...$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Tensor by $\mathcal{O}(-D)$. Do you recognize something ?

Comment: Generally speaking,  the short exact sequence is defined on a single fixed manifold. In the above case, the third sheaf (in the short exact sequence) is defined on the devisor  $D$ (not $M$).

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf defined on a **closed** subset $D$, we can take its pushforward $i_*\mathcal{F}$ along the inclusion $i:D\to M$. Often, we don't write $i_*$ and use again $\mathcal{F}$ for the pushforward. The property here is that $H^*(M,i_*\mathcal{F})=H^*(D,\mathcal{F})$ so writing $\mathcal{F}$ instead of $i_*\mathcal{F}$ is not a problem. This does not work for subset which are not closed though, in that case, it is really important to write the pushforward functor.

Comment: I understand that the short exact sequence should be rewrite as follows

$0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}([D]) \to i_*\{ \mathcal{O}([D])|D\} \to 0$ on the same fixed manifold $M$. Then use the usual procedure for a single base space. Finally use the isomorphism in your comments to change base space. Thank you, @Roland.

Comment: That's right, it is how it should be written, but now you know that $i_*$ can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you.
I didn't understand at first sight without the inclusion map.